# Parsing file with percent signs (%) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, text-parsing

I'm writing a parser for fortune files. Fortune is a small app on *nix platforms that just prints out a random "fortune". The fortune files are straight text, with each fortune being separated by a percent sign on its own line. For example:

```
A little suffering is good for the soul.
                -- Kirk, "The Corbomite Maneuver", stardate 1514.0
%
A man either lives life as it happens to him, meets it head-on and
licks it, or he turns his back on it and starts to wither away.
                -- Dr. Boyce, "The Menagerie" ("The Cage"), star date unknown
%
```

What I've found is that when parsing the file, stringWithContentsOfFile returns a string with the % signs in place. For example:

```
@"A little suffering is good for the soul.\n\t\t-- Kirk, \"The Corbomite Maneuver\", stardate 1514.0\n%\nA man either lives life as it happens to him, meets it head-on and\nlicks it, or he turns his back on it and starts to wither away.\n\t\t-- Dr. Boyce, \"The Menagerie\" (\"The Cage\"), stardate unknown\n%"
```

However, when I call componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet on the file contents, everything is parsed as a string, with the exception of the percent signs, which are NSTaggedPointerString. When I print out the lines, the percent signs are gone.

Is this because the percent sign is a format specifier for strings? I would think in that case that the initial content pull would escape those.

Here's the code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager;
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSStringEncoding stringEncoding;
//    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName usedEncoding:&stringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *fileLines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

The used encoding ends up being UTF-8. You can see I have also tried specifying plain ASCII, but it yields the same results.

So the question is, how do I retain the percent signs? Or, may I should use it as the separator character and then parse each of the subsequent results individually.

Comment: I printed the lines and the percent signs were still there in both examples you have.

Comment: @l'L'l weird. You used the same methods?

Comment: Yep, tried the uncommented and exactly what you have now — I used `NSLog(@"%@", fileLines);` ... this was the result: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/181ce0d4da733afd42740a0e3dfa676e

Comment: Ahh, I see something. I tried just NSLog'ing filesLines and got the same result you did. But, if I loop fileLines and NSLog the individual lines, the percent characters are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `NSLog()` but passing the line strings as the format string. Something like:

```
NSLog(lineString);
```

Therefore, any percent characters in the line strings are interpreted as format specifiers. You should (almost) never pass strings that come from outside sources — i.e. strings which are not hard-coded in your code — as format strings to any function (`NSLog()`, `printf()`, `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, etc.). It's not safe and you'll sometimes get unexpected results like you've seen.

You should always log a single string like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", lineString);
```

That is, you need to pass a hard-coded format string and use the foreign string as *data* for that to format.

Answer (score 0):

NSTaggedPointerString is just subclass of NSString. You can use anywhere as NSString.

But in your string

```
@"A little suffering is good for the soul.\n\t\t-- Kirk, \"The Corbomite Maneuver\", stardate 1514.0\n%\nA man either lives life as it happens to him, meets it head-on and\nlicks it, or he turns his back on it and starts to wither away.\n\t\t-- Dr. Boyce, \"The Menagerie\" (\"The Cage\"), stardate unknown\n%"
```

sign `%` is not percent sign. in Objective-C percent sign is declared as double of  `%` mark

```
@"%%"
```

Comment: Right, but I would have thought stringWithContentsOfFile would automatically escape those on import. I may have to drop down to C to handle the initial parsing.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There's no general need to escape percent in strings. Percent characters are only special in certain contexts, such as format strings to string-formatting functions. `@"%"` is a perfectly valid string containing a single percent character.

Comment: @KenThomases I don't think so. Ex with @"%d", You mean It will be really "%d" string?

Comment: @ABáo, yes, of course `@"%d"` is literally a string with a percent character and the letter 'd'. What else would it be? ***If*** such a string were passed to a string-formatting function, that function would see the percent and interpret it and the 'd' as a format specifier. Anyway, try it: `NSLog(@"%@", @"%d")`.